# Navigation Drawer not opening when I follow tutorial code

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming. I was trying to build navigation drawer and I followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/). The navigation drawer is not getting created and I am getting errors and the app is also terminating.

Below is my code

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);

     mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));



        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
                R.string.app_name){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();      
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {           
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Logging Out!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
        Intent i = new Intent(OptionsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);            
        startActivity(i);
        // return true;            
        OptionsActivity.this.finish();
    }

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
    return true;
}


/***
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new EventFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new EventsCalendarFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CmritForumFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new ChangePasswordFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

This is the fragment.xml file

```
`    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@string/home_view"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtLabel"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>


</RelativeLayout>    `
```

Comment: which errors are you getting?

Comment: I have posted my logcar error

Comment: the error means getActionBar() is returning null. You need to debug that first. Maybe there is no action bar in the activity?

Comment: Following upon @Ajibola's question - a potential reason you have no action bar might be the Theme your application is using. Make sure that Theme is one that includes an ActionBar (this is typically set in AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: I checked my manifest file. Theme is present there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing if you are using this in your code

```
   getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

to

```
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Or simply try changing ActionBarActivity to Activity.

You are not setting the click listener...please do this also

```
 mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
```

Comment: i have created fragments but I am not able to move to those fragments when I click on the navigation drawer menu. Can you help me with that

Comment: is the app crashing..what happens while you click on the slide menu items

Comment: Clicking on slider menu just closes the navigation bar. The app is not crashing

Comment: Check whether your displayView() method is getting called or not

Comment: I am also getting a warning that SliderMenuClickListener is never used locally

Comment: ok i think you have not initialized the click listener..Check my updated answer

Comment: I did as u said but the same issue is persisting

Comment: is this method displayView() getting called,   the warning is now gone r8?

Comment: The warning is removed but I am not able to figure out how to check whether a method is called or not

Comment: Just put System.out.println("inside method") in the displayView method .. and check whether is it printed on the logcat

Comment: Yes the message is getting printed on logcat

Comment: Well check whether the fragments oncreateView is called on each position fragments...

Comment: Yes onCreateView is called on each fragment

Comment: Do you have any views in each fragments...can add home fragment and its xml here

Comment: `package com.abhineel.i_student;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
 
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
     
    public HomeFragment(){}
     
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
          
        return rootView;
    }
}`

Comment: Actually i think each fragments are called but every xml.had the same content....try to add a textview to each fragment xml wirh its corresponding names and run..

Answer (score 0):

you are getting and null from this line:

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

you need to check why your action bar is null.
can you post your class itself?
does your class extends ActionBarActivity?

Comment: Yes class extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: public class OptionsActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarDrawerToggle's constructor

public ActionBarDrawerToggle (Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, int drawerImageRes, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes)

Click [here] 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle